# How to run DB Admin Tool (GUI) in IBM DB2 Express-C?

Tags: db2

I had installed IBM DB2 Express-C in Windows but I can't find any shortcut to launch the Administration Tools (GUI). When installing, I had selected "Administration Tool" option (I had checked twice to make sure).

This is the only shortcuts available from Start Menu:

[image: IBM DB2 Shortcuts]

So how to run the Administration Tools for IBM DB2 Express-C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DB2 Express-C version 10 and later no longer include a full suite of administration tools as part of the installer (the "Administration Tools" you installed might only include the ones you're looking at...).

Like MySQL and SQL Server, the administration tools are now available as a separate download.

The official tool you're looking for is [IBM Data Studio](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/data-studio), which is available free of charge.

Older versions of DB2 Express-C used to include the legacy Control Center apps, but [IBM has deprecated those](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/i0054250.html) and is really pushing the Eclipse-based Data Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a universal db admin tool for IBM DB2 also.
My favorite is DBeaver Community Edition.